# How to update Windows 10 to 1803?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1803

I have a windows 10 tablet that I reset and then it went back to windows 10 1511. Now I want to update it to 1803. I don't want to get the latest version (1909 as of the moment). That's because I'm testing our software for compatibility with 1803. I need to make sure our app will run smoothly on 1803.

How can I do that?

Comment: I have done the above and Windows Update will go from V1511 to the current version. You may try going to the Microsoft Download site and see if you can download the V1803 ISO. Then use that to upgrade your machine.

Comment: You would need to simply download a Windows 10 version 1803 ISO.  If for some reason that process fails, and it might fail, you would have to first upgrade to 1607, 1703, 1709, then finally 1803.  The upgrade process was improved significantly with the release of 1703.  **Tools designed to determine the reason an upgrade fails are not compatible with Windows 10 version 1511.**

Comment: Make sure to do this update either offline, or select the "Do not check for updates" when installing the 1803 ISO.

Comment: I had to download the ISO and run the setup manually after installing. I got the iso from the msdn subscriber portal. Thanks everyone!